# One must experience and process death to see Thestrals. But *must* one physically witness it?

Tags: harry-potter

Inspired by the famous question, something subtle about it struck me.

Harry definitely witnessed and dealt with Cedric's death. It took a while before he could see the Thestrals because it takes a while to process loss. Luna can see them because of her mother's death. I believe Hagrid can see them because of one or both of his parents' deaths.

Now, is there any evidence to say if Hagrid and Luna literally witnessed death (reasonably unusual but it happens - though Luna would have seen her mother's particularly unpleasant sounding death, poor girl) or does experiencing the loss and processing the passing count? In this case, most Hogwarts age students should probably be able to see the Thestrals assuming that the death of a grandparent or other relative would count.

So, do you need to witness death, or experience a loved one's passing?

Comment: That answer actually says "You must process death," which I understand and include in my question. But *must* you *witness* it? Can everyone who's grandma died see them, or do you need to actually have been present, as Luna sounds a bit like she might have been?

Comment: The dupehammer is strong today....

Comment: Yes, you must witness death, and then fully process the meaning of what you have seen. I think that answer is pretty clear, as well as JKR's comments. Yes, Luna saw her mother die; she subsequently can see Thestrals.

Comment: Please read the comment by J.K. Rowling. I think you are overanalyzing this.

Comment: @Jonah -- I'm not sure what you mean. I read it as a duplicate, therefore I closed it as a duplicate. Nothing to look at there.

Comment: @Slytherincess - I totally agree. It is a duplicate. It's just that there are three dupe questions at the top of the new questions queue (so the dupehammer is strong today).

Comment: @Slitherincess - I read it before I asked this question, read it when you marked it a dupe, and read it again now. She says that Harry saw it and couldn't see them, then processed it and could. I am simply wondering if it is explicitly stated somewhere that you must see it, or experience the loss of a significant person. I am taking care not to say "just" experience the loss, as the impact is not to be underestimated.

Comment: Well, Hermione does say that only those who have "seen death" can perceive thestrals.

Comment: @Jonah - OK, I do sound like I'm over thinking it now no doubt, but that does sound like it may or may not be literal (as in she might well be simplifying a huge issue). I hope someone out there might just chuck a further clarifying quote my way.

Comment: @Jonah -- Ah, okay. I access the site a little differently, so I don't see the main page, and never know exactly how many dupes are leading the charge! :)

Comment: @Slytherincess how do you access the site?